# DynamoDB adds item instead of updates item when using update_item

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an html table that is filled from a DynamoDB table. Clicking a row pops up an edit form in a modal. The data inputted is sent to a flask server to update the item - using AWS DynamoDB - that was edited in the modal form. Upon reading the AWS documentation for this, the correct method is to use `update_item`. However, when doing so the item is added again instead of updating the item. I used the AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.03) to script the below. In my DynamoDB table, the `primary partition key` is `KEY1` and the `primary sort key` is `KEY2` in the below reference.

```
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name') #define DynamoDB table
key1 = account_id #string value of account id
key2 = request.form["KEY2"] #this is a read only field in the form, so the key does not get updated here
form_val1 = request.form["input1"]
form_val2 = request.form["input2"]
form_val3 = request.form["input3"]
form_val4 = request.form["input4"]
form_val5 = request.form["input5"]
form_val6 = request.form["input6"]
form_val7 = request.form["input7"]
form_val8 = request.form["input8"]
form_val9 = request.form["input9"]
            
#update item in dynamo     
table.update_item(
             Key={
             'KEY1': key1, #partition key
             'KEY2': key2 #sort key
             },
             UpdateExpression='SET dbField1 = :val1, dbField2 = :val2, dbField3 = :val3, dbField4 = :val4, dbField5 = :val5, dbField6 = :val6, dbField7 = :val7, dbField8 = :val8, dbField9 = :val9',
             ExpressionAttributeValues={
             ':val1': form_val1, 
             ':val2': form_val2, 
             ':val3': form_val3, 
             ':val4': form_val4,
             ':val5': form_val5, 
             ':val6': form_val6, 
             ':val7': form_val7, 
             ':val8': form_val8, 
             ':val9': form_val9
             }
             )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and I will explain to you for what that not is possible.

When you create a table on dynamo DB with key and a order key you automatically create an index between key and sort key. We know an index is inmutable, that means you can't update the keys. Is for that reason that when you update dynamo create a new element.

It's a problem of the definition of your table because you never need to change the key or the sort key. Recreate your table only with the index and not with the sort index (because if your app can change the sort index that make not sense).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and I think I get what you saying. However, I should have clarified that the partition and sort keys are not being updated. `KEY1` is from a variable on the server, `KEY2` is in the html form which is "read only", so only the attributes are being updated. I will edit the original post accordingly

Comment: can you please print your values of key before insert? I think... maybe your key have 
 space... try to trim the values if you are sure the key and sort exist

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to check for white spaces. It was indeed the issue, and solved my problem. I will mark your answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full query?  the `update_item` docs say that `TableName` is required, which I don't see in your snippet.

From the [updateitem docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html):

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table
> if it does not already exist.

Make sure that the primary key (partition key *and* sort key) are unique in your table.  If they are not, `updateitem` will create a new item in the database.

Are you absolutely certain that the primary key for the item already exists in the database?

Comment: Yep that's the full query. I tried to add table parameter as you suggested, no success. Primary key definitely does exist - as in the original post the data in the html table is read from the DynamoDB table - when clicking a row the item is represented on a form to edit the respective item upon form submission.

Comment: I'm not sure why this code snippet would update anything in DDB, given that you haven't provided all the required parameters to updateitem.  Is this the actual code, or just an example?  How are you defining the table variable?  

How are you confirming the state of the database before and after the updateitem operation is executed?  The DDB console, a CLI query, something else?

Comment: It's the actual code - variables have been changed. I have made a small edit to OP, I define the table variable the same way I delete and add new items `table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')`. I'll try print logs from the db console

Comment: Providing logs with the actual data may be helpful.
Can you clarify what you mean when you say the item is "added again"?

Comment: Thanks for your input Seth. Per the other answer, the issue was infact white spaces. Silly mistake